# How to handle chrome windows that pop up

Tags: scala, selenium

So in my scenario i am click on some button:

```
val button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("...."))
button.click
```

So my problem is that after this click `google chrome` pop up little windows that i need to confirm and since this not part of the `HTML` i cannot reach this `window`, also i am working on `MAC` so there is no `AutoIt` that can catch this `window`.

[image]

Any suggestions how to click on this window `button` ?

Comment: What kind of popup is it? Is it an alert?

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: What is the popup about?

Comment: @davidhol - is that a JavaScript alert? or application specific?